# How do I create a custom navigation bar that retains the title, leftBarButtonItem, and rightBarButtonItem. But, has three bigger buttons below them

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Picture this:
Hamburger menu on the left, an image where title is, and another barButtonItem on the right - Then three buttons below that is like a tabBarController, but it all has to be seamless and connected to one UINavigationBar.

///-----------------title ----------------- <>

BUTTON 1 BUTTON 2 BUTTON 3

How should one go about implementing this? I was thinking about creating a custom UINavigationBar. But then how do I add subviews below barButtonsItem to the navigationBar?

Any push in direction is greatly appreciated

Comment: This isn't a code writing/interface building service. What have you tried? Try looking through the interface components in Xcode (the little box at the bottom right in the interface builder).

Comment: I created a custom UINavigationBar and was able to manipulate its height. However, adding three subviews below renders to be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to customize a UINavigationBar. You can create the appearance of an extended Navigation Bar placing a view at the bottom of the navigation bar, disabling the bar's translucency, setting the bar's shadow image to a clear image, setting it's background image to a solid color, then drawing a hairline drop shadow below the view. You can then add your buttons to that. For example, you can setup the view in IB, the add:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentPixel"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pixel"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In the viewDidLoad of the view controller you want the extended navigation view. Then in the subclass of UIView of the view to extend your navigation bar, you can say:

```
- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow
{
    [self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1.0f/UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)];
    [self.layer setShadowRadius:0];

    [self.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.25f];

}
```

This is probably still somewhat confusing. Fortunately, Apple has provided annotated [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html) to show you exactly how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If nobody responded, my second question would of been your answer to removing the line that the navigation bar has. SO, thank you for your help